# Scons fails to install a directory when using variants

Tags: scons

I can use the `Install()` builder to install a directory, provided I don't use a variant.

Example without a variant (works fine):

```
$ mkdir -p test/src/doc
$ cd test
$ echo "SConscript('src/SConscript', exports={'dst': '/tmp'})" > SConstruct
$ echo xyz > src/doc/file
$ echo "Import('dst')" > src/SConscript
$ echo "Install(dst, 'doc')" >> src/SConscript
$ scons /tmp
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install directory: "src/doc" as "/tmp/doc"
scons: done building targets.
$ scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
    engine: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 The SCons Foundation
```

Example with a variant (does not work):

```
$ echo "SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0, exports={'dst': 'install'})" > SConstruct
$ scons build
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install file: "build/doc" as "build/install/doc"
scons: *** [build/install/doc] build/doc: No such file or directory
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

This appears to be a very odd behaviour... For my current project, I want to be able to install a directory tree (typically documentation), but using variants.

Could anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of scons ? (2.4.1) That'd be the first thing to try.

Comment: I just tried with scons-2.4.1, and I have exactly the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, it seems scons tries to install directories using the given path relative from the variant directory, which obviously points to a non-existent folder.

I solved the problem by using absolute paths. Using my toy example:

```
$ mkdir -p test/src/doc
$ cd test
$ echo "import os" > SConstruct
$ echo "SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0, exports={'cwd': os.getcwd() + '/src', 'dst': '/tmp'})" >> SConstruct
$ echo xyz > src/doc/file
$ echo "Import('cwd dst')" > SConscript
$ echo "Install(dst, cwd + '/doc')" >> SConscript
$ scons /tmp
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install directory: "src/doc" as "/tmp/doc"
scons: done building targets.
```

Problem solved! Hope this helps.

Comment: Could  you use "#/doc" as the source dir in your Install statement?  (From man page "An initial # (hash mark) on a path name means that the rest of the file name is interpreted relative to the directory containing the top-level SConstruct file, even if the # is followed by a directory separator character (slash or backslash).")

Comment: Also `Glob` knows to look for files in both, source and variant dir paths